# Not able to access tables using dblinks in Sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

DB Link Creation was successful with the below query

```
create database link dblink1 connect to "uname" identified by "password" using 'sid';
```

Post that while trying to access a table present in the target db using the dblink with the below query

```
select * from dual@dblink1;
```

It is failing with the below error

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
>
> ORA-02063: preceding line from dblink1
>
> 1017. 00000 -  "invalid username/password; logon denied"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:
>
> Error at Line: 3 Column: 19

NOTE:

1. All the actions are done through SQLDeveloper
2. Username and password provided at the time of creation of the dblink are proper(correct).

Answer (score 1):

Your note says that the username/password are correct, however by using double quotes you are forcing them to be interpreted in case specified. Unless you created the user in the same way, it will most likely be stored in upper case.

So instead try without the double quotes:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK dblink1 CONNECT TO uname IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'sid';
```